# DataSource initialization error within liberty profile server

Tags: java, jdbc, datasource, websphere-liberty

I am trying to set up a DataSource in liberty profile server, but I'm getting a `NullPointerException` (on my ds variable below) when my code tries to use it.

The relevant code, and `server.xml` entries are below.
Interestingly, if I change the jndiName to `java:comp/env/jdbc/Oracle` I get an `IllegalArgumentException` on server startup, but with the config below it doesn't even seem to try to activate the DataSource...

```
public abstract class DAOBase {
    //@Resource(name = "jdbc/Oracle", type = javax.sql.DataSource.class, shareable = true, authenticationType = AuthenticationType.CONTAINER)
    @Resource(lookup = "jdbc/Oracle")
    private DataSource ds;


protected Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
    return conn;
}
```

My `server.xml` config:

```
<featureManager>
    <feature>jsp-2.2</feature>
    <feature>jaxrs-1.1</feature>
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
    <feature>appSecurity-2.0</feature>
    <feature>jpa-2.0</feature>
    <feature>jdbc-4.0</feature>
    <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
</featureManager>

<library id="OracleJDBC_ID">
    <fileset dir="C:\src\main\lib" includes="ojdbc6.jar"/>
</library>
<jdbcDriver id="OracleDriver" libraryRef="OracleJDBC_ID"/>

<dataSource jdbcDriverRef="OracleDriver" jndiName="jdbc/Oracle">
    <properties.oracle URL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://oid:***/opl***,cn=OracleContext,dc=****,dc=com" password="****" user="*****"/>
</dataSource>
```

Error in the log:

```
[ERROR   ] CWWKE0701E: [com.ibm.ws.jdbc.dataSource(200)] The modified method has
thrown an exception Bundle:com.ibm.ws.jdbc(id=82) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
J2CA8011E: Value java:comp/env/jdbc/Oracle is not supported for jndiName on dataSource
    at com.ibm.ws.jdbc.DataSourceService.activate(DataSourceService.java:209)
    at [internal classes]
```

EDIT:
The code is in the base class for our Data Access layer. We're calling this in a RESTful web service via a very plain initialization:

```
AuditDAO auditDAO = new AuditDAO();
```

Comment: Using `jndiName="java:comp/..."` is wrong as the IllegalArgumentException suggests.  If the `@Resource` was working, it would be responsible for creating the `java:comp/env/jdbc/Oracle`, and then the default binding would be `jdbc/Oracle`, which would match your jndiName.  However, the `@Resource` doesn't seem to be working.  What kind of class contains the `@Resource`, and how are you creating instances of that class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@Resource` will not work in POJO unless you activate CDI. Try the following:

- add beans.xml file to the `WEB-INF` folder, and add CDI feature

> ```
> <feature>cdi-1.0</feature>
> ```

- inject auditDAO to your web service using `@Inject AuditDAO auditDAO`
- use the following reference in the dao

> ```
>    @Resource(name="jdbc/Oracle", lookup = "jdbc/Oracle")
>    private DataSource ds;
> ```

Comment: That worked well, thanks very much, but I have another question for a more complicated scenario: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27044253/cdi-injection-through-multiple-levels