# CDI Injection through multiple levels?

Tags: java, cdi, websphere-liberty

I am using CDI to initialize a DataSource (See my previous question: [DataSource initialization error within liberty profile server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27024140/datasource-initialization-error-within-liberty-profile-server))

```
public abstract class DAOBase {
    @Resource(name="jdbc/Oracle", lookup = "jdbc/Oracle")
    private DataSource ds;
```

This works well when the DAO class is initialized directly from the REST class:

```
@Path("/audit")
public class AuditREST extends RESTBase implements AuditRESTInterface {
    @Inject
    private AuditDAO auditDAO = new AuditDAO();
```

And when the REST class calls an intermediate class which calls the DAO I can do it by:

```
public class JobConfigurationREST extends RESTBase implements JobConfigurationRESTInterface {
    @Inject
    private JobRunner jr = new JobRunner();

public class JobRunner implements Runnable{
    @Inject
    private JobConfigurationDAO jcDAO = new JobConfigurationDAO();
```

However JobRunner also contains a method which creates some instances of a class (SampleModel) on the fly. SampleModel then contains a dao which I need to inject.

```
public class SampleModel extends Step implements Model {
    @Inject
    private ModelDAO modelDAO = new ModelDAO();
```

I can see no way of adding the link between JobRunner and SampleModel. How do I do this?

Alternatively, is this even necessary? I feel that having to specify all the links between the REST class and the DAO class is overly complicated, and I should be able to declare SampleModel somewhere (possibly beans.xml?), and the container should take care of everything for me.

EDIT:

I was simplifying the problem here.
SampleModel is created via a Job class which is created via a method in a JobBuilder class (which I also can't seem to inject).

```
JobBuilder jb = new JobBuilder();
Job j = jb.buildJob(jc, jobContext);
```

SampleModel is also created via reflection deep within the buildJob method.

```
    public Job buildJob(JobConfiguration inJobConfiguration, JobContext inJobContext) {
stepList.add(ModelFactory.getInstance().getModel(sc.getImplementationName()));
    }
```

And within the Factory:

ret = (Model) Class.forName(tmpImplDetail.getClassName()).newInstance();

Comment: James, when you do `@Inject` don't construct using `new`. Just write `@Inject private JobRunner jr;` Please also show how you are using SampleModel.

Comment: Is that just for JobRunnner? Is @Inject
    private AuditDAO auditDAO = new AuditDAO(); wrong also? I'll update the question with details for SampleModel

Comment: It is in general. Because the whole idea is that container is **injecting** instance, not you creating it by hand (by `new`).

Comment: Aha, that starts to make sense. I think what I'm having difficulty with is injecting an instance deep within my call stack. It's easy when down from the REST layer at the start, but I would really like to  ignore the first three or four layers, and inject just at the last possible moment. (If that's possible?)

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the code. In general - when you use `new` or `Class.forName` resources are not injected, since these instances are not managed by the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem appears to be that you want to move your @Inject into a class that is not a component the container performs injection on.

This is masked by the way you're assigning a new'ed up object to your injection point.

- In components that actually do support injection, the injection process will happen *after* the assignment and make it harmless.
- In objects that the container does not inject for you, you get an object allocated by new that will not have any of its own injection points satisfied.

If you were not doing the weird assignment thing, you'd be asking more of an FAQ of "why is my @Inject field NULL?"

Comment: ok. So how do I get round this? Available options that I see are: (a) Get the container to inject the Resource at the REST level (which is a bit icky but would work) (b) somehow tell the container about my class so it can perform injection on it. (if that's possible??)

Comment: I've got round the problem by using a JNDI lookup for the case where I cannot inject. Not quite as quick, but at least it works.